# How to debug Htmlunit traffic with Fiddler using PAC (proxy auto-config)

Tags: debugging, proxy, fiddler, htmlunit, pac

I have an application using Htmlunit and need put Fiddler to intercept traffic, i read something about configure it via PAC (proxy auto-config) javascript file that comes with but i cant found the article again. How to configure Htmlunit via PAC ? Where the PAC javascript is located ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*"Fiddler is an HTTP Proxy running on port 8888 on your local PC.  You can configure any application which accepts a HTTP Proxy to run through Fiddler so you can debug its traffic."*
([hookup](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp))
Try it:

```
 WebClient wc = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_2, "127.0.0.1", 8888);
```

OR

*"You can get the correct auto-configuration URL from Fiddler by clicking Tools / Fiddler Options / Connections, and clicking the 'Copy Browser Proxy Configuration URL' link."*
([hookup](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp))
Try it:

```
 wc.getProxyConfig().setProxyAutoConfigUrl(strUrl);
```